# How to turning off "last seen" and "active" on Facebook messages?

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-messenger

I do not use the Facebook app or the Message app. I have "chat" turned off. Yet, everyone can see (if they click on a past message from me or message they have sent) it shows "active" or "last seen". Why turn your chat off for privacy when, it shows my status in my messages? Am I the only one that's upset about this? Please help with this showing?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you're not able to hide the last time you were active on Facebook. If you'd like to provide feedback to the messages product team about this, please visit our Help Center:

https://www.facebook.com/help/feedback/?ref=u2u